# How does indexing change when deleting a record from a DAO recordset?

Tags: vba, ms-access, indexing, dao, recordset

I'm writing a VBA script to 1) pick up a recordset [rs], 2) compare [data] in every record [i] to every other record 3) if the records are the same delete record [i], 4) continue 2)

Here's a snippet for reference:

```
rs.MoveLast
n_records = rs.RecordCount

For i = 1 to n_records
  rs.Move i
  data = rs![Data]
  Do
     rs.MoveNext
     data_current = rs![Data]
     If (data = data_current) Then 
        rs.Move i
        rs.Delete
        GoTo NextIteration
     End If
  Loop Until rs.EOF
  NextIteration:
Next
```

My question is: what happens to the indexing of a recordset once a record has been deleted?

e.g. if I had 100 records and the first For iteration(i=1) found a duplicate and deleted record[1]; would the indexing reset? Will record[2] now become record[1] and will the #records be 99? And if so; in For(i=2); is rs moving to what was originally record[3]?!

Comment: I'm not adept with access, but I'm pretty certain that `n_records` will remain 100 and record[2] will remain record[2]. If this is anything similar to excel, you'll need to step backwards through your loop deleting records instead (i.e. `For i = n_records to 1 Step -1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dwirony's approach is a good one.

Access doesn't definitively delete records. It works with transactions, and keeps record of rows it has deleted. A recordset contains positions for deleted rows. Doing anything with a deleted row (navigating to or from it, reading values) will trigger run-time error 3167: record is deleted.

Your current code has numerous misconceptions, however. For example, `rs.Move` moves a recordset a fixed number of places from the current record, not from the start. You can avoid this behavior by setting a bookmark at the start of the recordset, and passing that to `rs.Move`. But that causes problems if the recordset gets deleted.

My advice: open up the recordset twice (using `.RecordsetClone`). Use rs.MoveNext and bookmarks: set the bookmark of the first recordset equal to that of the second one (to sync them up), then move the second one one place forward.

Example:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Something")
Set rsClone = rs.RecordsetClone

Do Until rs.EOF
  rsClone.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
  Do Until rsClone.EOF
     rsrsClone.MoveNext
     data_current = rs![Data]
     If (data = data_current) Then 
        rsClone.Delete
        GoTo NextIteration
     End If
  Loop Until rsClone.EOF
  NextIteration:
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```